# ID Cambiante en HTML

Tags: html

Estoy haciendo una macro que coloque en un `input` la fecha del día actual menos 45 días y en otro la fecha del día actual, el caso es que en código `html` el **ID** cambia constantemente por ejemplo:

```
<input class="clsSelectDateEditBox" id="txtDateN1A6B8D20x185CACF0_NS_" aria-invalid="false" type="text" value="">
```

y al momento de darle `refresh` pasa esto

```
<input class="clsSelectDateEditBox" id="txtDateN2A924CE0x23B62CF0_NS_" aria-invalid="false" type="text" value="">
```

Como se ve cambió el **ID**, también intente hacerlo de la manera en que buscara la posición en la cuál se encontraba (séptima posición, octava, etc.) pero de igual manera cambia por lo que quería solicitar de su ayuda para resolver este problema.

Mi avance la macro hasta el momento es este:

```
Sub PROYECTOPRUEBA()
Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim document As HTMLDocument
Dim fecha As String
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

IE.Navigate "https://ca-dtna.app.corpintra.net/ibmcognos/bi/v1/disp?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=%2fcontent%2fpackage%5b%40name%3d%27Vehicle%20Shortages%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27VS104%20-%20Shortage%20Details%20by%20Item%20Number%27%5d&ui.name=VS104%20-%20Shortage%20Details%20by%20Item%20Number&run.outputFormat=&run.prompt=true"
IE.Visible = True

Do
    DoEvents

Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

Debug.Print IE.document.getElementById("txtDateN2A924CE0x23B62CF0_NS_").Value
IE.document.getElementById("txtDateN2A924CE0x23B62DCC_NS_").Value = DateValue(Now)

End Sub
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Y buscarlo por clase?

Comment: ¿Cómo sería? Dado que los dos tienen la misma clase pero de igual manera cambian de posición

Comment: En vez de buscar por id buscar clase. Solo es una idea, solo tenemos 2 muestras y veo que en las 2 esta la misma clase.

Comment: ¿Has intentado usando [selectores de atributos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo)? Algo así como 
`IE.document.querySelector('input[id^="txtDate"]').value`

Comment: Una pregunta y en html como sería? Por que no me dejo hacer tal modificiación, al parecer por que el uso de dicha herramienta es para CSS.

Comment: Con JQuery seri muy facil: $(".clsSelectDateEditBox").val();